# Pod keeps failing and restarting with FailedPostStartHook

Tags: kubernetes, vault

When I go to add something like below to my `envFrom` in spec.template.spec.containers and remove envconsul the pod will fail to start then gets stuck in a reboot loop and all it says is `FailedPostStartHook` is failing which all it does is create a tmp directory.

```
- secretRef:
    name: [SECRET NAME]
```

I double checked the name of the secret compared to the name defined in my `VaultStaticSecret` and it matches perfectly. The `VaultStaticSecret` also created fine and no errors.

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.